# Validating Range quantity from user input for generating random numbers in php

Tags: php, validation

I have a function where in I allow my clients to generate random numbers on my site.

**Here is the PHP function**

```
function UniqueRandomNumbers($min, $max, $quantity)
{
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
```

I am allowing the maximum `quantity` of `10000 numbers` when they submit a form using `From` and `To` inputs.

I would like to validate if a user submits the range more than 10000 numbers then validation should throw an error. For example, if a client uses 10000 in `From input` and 30000 in `To input` then it should throw an error rather than processing the request.

I tried with several stuff, but was not lucky enough to get through.

How could I validate the max range of 10000 numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if count() > 10000`, or `if $max - $min > 10000`

Comment: You are seriously not able to figure out a simple _subtraction_ operation yourself …? Wow.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks it worked perfectly, I voted up... Thanks for the help

Comment: @CBroe yes, sometimes, I miss out on simple operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(($max - $min) > 10000) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```
function UniqueRandomNumbers($min, $max, $quantity)
{
    if($max > 10000 || $min > 10000){
       return -1;
    }

    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function UniqueRandomNumbers($min, $max, $quantity)
{
    if (($max - $min) > $quantity) {
       throw new Exception('Your range is exceeding your quantity.');
    }

    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
```

Or am I understanding your question wrong?